# Python [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, window

At first this script run fine but after it show this error `"[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified"` without changing anything in the script

```
import os

paths = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Film\OneDrive\Documents\WORK\Blockfint\Richy_csv_files\Recovery_as_compu_11_14_2022_14_9_32\Tables')

def files_with_word(word:str, paths:list) -> str:
    for path in paths:
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            if word in f.read():
                yield path


for filepath in files_with_word("Admin", paths):
    print(filepath)
```

I try uninstall all python and reinstall with `python 3.11 64 bit` it still not working

Comment: It may be a silly question, but your path still exists right? As a test try specifying a different folder,. Also, I would change the raw string to a normal string and just escape the backslashes. change `paths = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Film\OneDrive\Documents\WORK\Blockfint\Richy_csv_files\Recovery_as_compu_11_14_2022_14_9_32\Tables')` to `paths = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Film\\OneDrive\\Documents\\WORK\\Blockfint\\Richy_csv_files\\Recovery_as_compu_11_14_2022_14_9_32\\Tables')`

Comment: Yes the paths still existed and I doesn’t touch anything in the script or file location

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having looks like it is with not using absolute paths. `paths = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Film\OneDrive\Documents\WORK\Blockfint\Richy_csv_files\Recovery_as_compu_11_14_2022_14_9_32\Tables')` will just get a list of filenames with no path info. So if you are not actually running the python file while in the same directory it will produce that file not found error.

In the for loop I just ocncantenated the source directory and filename together to get the full path to open.
You will also want to filter out directories since the current code would also try to open a directory as a file and cause an error.

```
import os

src = r'C:\Users\Film\OneDrive\Documents\WORK\Blockfint\Richy_csv_files\Recovery_as_compu_11_14_2022_14_9_32\Tables'
files = os.listdir(src)


# only get files. filter out directories 
files = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(src+'/'+f)] 


def files_with_word(word:str, files:list) -> str:
    for file in files:
        # create full path to file
        full_path = src + "\\" + file
       
        #open using full path
        print(full_path)
        with open(full_path, "r") as f:
            if word in f.read():
                yield file


for filepath in files_with_word("Admin", files):
    print(filepath)
```